# Mapping user space to physical memory

Tags: linux, memory-management

I know that there are three zones in physical memory:

```
ZONE_DMA - Contains page frames of memory below 16 MB
ZONE_NORMAL - Contains page frames of memory at and above 16 MB and below 896 MB
ZONE_HIGHMEM - Contains page frames of memory at and above 896 MB
```

But i'm wondering that where is the user-space(3G) exist on these zones? And how to map user-space to physical memory? Please help me understand.

Comment: As for your first question, "anywhere". Because that's how MMUs work.

Comment: As far as i know, kernel space will be mapped from 0-896MB area, which is corresponding to ZONE_DMA and ZONE_NORMAL, so user space is mapped to ZONE_HIGH?

Comment: Can someone tell me how this is a duplicate of the one linked? The answer there does not even begins to address this question.